# A basis of a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ be a set of vectors in a vector space $V$. Show that $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ is a basis of $V$ if and only if for any non-zero linear function $f$ on $V$ there is a vector $v$ in $\operatorname{span}(v_1, \ldots, v_n)$ such that $f(v) \neq 0$.

Suppose that $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ is not a basis of $V$. Then the complement $W$ of $\operatorname{span}(v_1, \ldots, v_n)$ in $V$ is not empty. Let $f$ be a function such that $f(x)=1$ for all $x\in W$ and $f(x)=0$ for all $x$ in $\operatorname{span}(v_1, \ldots, v_n)$. My question is: is $f$ linear in $V$?

Comment: No, $f$ is not linear unless $W$ is empty: pick $w\in W$, and let $x=w$; then $f(2x) = 1$ (because $2x\in W$), but $2f(x) = 2$, so $f$ is not homogeneous. It is also not additive: take $x=w$, and $y=v_1-w$. Then $f(x)=f(y)=1$, but $f(x+y) = f(v_1) = 0\neq f(x)+f(y)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every linear transformation is determined by its values on a basis. These values may be chosen arbitrarily. So, your $f$ is a linear functional on $V$ if you require that $f(x)=1$ for a basis of $W$, not for the whole of $W$. A constant function cannot be linear unless it is zero.

Comment: $W$ is not a subspace: it's the complement of a subspace, so it doesn't even have a zero vector. What is "a basis for $W$"?

Comment: Oh, I read $W$ as a *linear* complement of $\operatorname{span}(v_1, \ldots, v_n)$, ie, a subspace such that $V=W \bigoplus\operatorname{span}(v_1, \ldots, v_n)$.

Comment: I guess that's a possible reading... fair enough

Answer (score 3):

Um, unless I'm misreading the question, the thing to be proved is false. Counterexample: Let $V=\mathbb R^1$ (a real vector space) and let $n=2$, $v_1=5$, and $v_2=42$. Then $\mathrm{span}(5,42)$ is $\mathbb R^1$ itself, and it is certainly the case that for any nonzero linear $f$, there is a vector $v$ in $\mathbb R^1$ such that $f(v)\ne 0$ -- that is the *definition* of $f$ being nonzero.

But the set $(v_1,v_2)$ is not a basis for $\mathbb R^1$ because it is linearly dependent; to wit, $42v_1-5v_2=0$.

Answer (score 1):

As Henning points out, the statement is false as written; but if you add the assumption that $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ are linearly independent, then the result is true.

As to your idea, it's either completely wrong or *almost* right, depending on what you mean by "complement."

If by "complement" you mean the set-theoretic complement (that is, $W$ is the set of all vectors in $V$ that are not in $\mathrm{span}(v_1,\ldots,v_n)$), which was my interpretation when I read your post, then your approach is completely wrong: this set is not closed under sums, and in general you cannot expect it to be well-behaved.

If by "complement" you mean a *linear* complement (as lhs understood your writing), that is, a subspace $W$ such that $W\cap\mathrm{span}(v_1,\ldots,v_n)=\{\mathbf{0}\}$ and $W+\mathrm{span}(v_1,\ldots,v_n) = V$), then you are *almost* right: you cannot define $f$ as $1$ on *all* of $W$ (that would not be homogeneous or additive); but you *can* find a basis for $W$ (say, by extending $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ to a basis of $V$, $v_1,\ldots,v_n,v_{n+1},\ldots,v_{n+m}$ and letting $W=\mathrm{span}(v_{n+1},\ldots,v_{n+m})$), define $f$ as $1$ *on that basis*, and then "extending linearly".